# Type mismatch (Error 13) when using vba to trim values

Tags: excel, vba, trim, type-mismatch

I have a data report that comes from another company. One of the fields I need to use has about 30 extra trailing spaces (I have no idea why) in each row. I only need to work with some of the columns, so what I've done is pick data from a column one at a time and drop it into a new sheet in an order that suits my analysis. I don't use copy & paste for this, I use `worksheets("A").range("...").value = worksheets("B").range("...").value`.
This works to grab the columns I want and place them in the order I want. After reorganizing, I tried this to trim the cells in the column:

```
    Worksheets("B").Range("F2:F" & rw).Value = Trim(Worksheets("B").Range("F2:F" & rw).Value)
```

I've tried tweaking this line based on google searches, but every time I get a Type mismatch (Error 13) right here. rw is a variable I've set for the number of rows my data lives in. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I added a loop:

```
myArr = Worksheets("B").Range("F2:F" & rw).Value
For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
    myArr(i, 1) = Trim(myArr(i, 1))
Next i
Worksheets("B").Range("F2:F" & rw).Value = myArr
```

It does what I want now.

Comment: `Trim` and `Application.Trim` (which is the late-bound version of `WorksheetFunction.Trim`) work differently. The former does not remove extra spaces inbetween words... but if you're not concerned about that, then you could use `Application.Trim` in place of `Trim` here.

Comment: Trim() only works with strings.  I suspect your complex expression,  `Worksheets("B").Range("F2:F" & rw).Value`, resolves to something that's NOT a string.  SUGGESTION: "divide and conquer": break the complex expression down into smaller sub-variables to determine exactly where the problem lies...

Comment: @paulsm4 - yep, it's a 2D Variant array.

Comment: @paulsm4 everything in that column is a string. It's a bunch of lastname, firstname with a ton of added spaces. How would that result in something that isn't a string?

Comment: @BrettRussellAce - because the `.Value` of a multi-cell range is a 2D Variant array, which `Trim` will choke on. Based on your description, try using `Application.Trim`.

Comment: @BigBen I'd prefer not removing the middle spaces as the column is names, but I tried `Application.Trim` and it didn't work either. Actually, intellisense didn't think it existed.

Comment: Because it is the late-bound version of `WorksheetFunction.Trim`, so yes, you don't get Intellisense. This would only remove *extra* middle spaces, working exactly as the formula`=TRIM(...)` does. But if you don't want to use `Application.Trim`, then you have to loop over each cell.

Comment: @BigBen Ok, I guess I'm making a loop. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting Type mismatch (Error 13) is because Trim() only works with strings, but you're attempting to trim an array.

SOLUTION:

1. If you're assigning a string to a single cell, then:

   a. Concatenate the string variables you wish, then

   b. Trim() the string, and assign it to your cell
2. Otherwise, if you're copying a collection of strings from one range to another range, then

   a. Do as BigBen suggests, and use a loop

Comment: Fair enough - I updated my response accordingly.  The key point is that the OP needs to understand that an *array of strings* <> "string"

Answer (score 0):

### Trim

- You will have to loop:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub testRange()
    
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "F2"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B")
    
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Set LastCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, _
      ws.Range(FirstCellAddress).Column).End(xlUp)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(FirstCellAddress, LastCell)
    
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        cel.Value = Trim(cel.Value)
    Next cel
    
End Sub

Sub testArray()
    
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "F2"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("B")
    
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Set LastCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, _
      ws.Range(FirstCellAddress).Column).End(xlUp)
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(FirstCellAddress, LastCell)
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = rng.Value
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        Data(i, 1) = Trim(Data(i, 1))
    Next i
    
    rng.Value = Data
    
End Sub
```